# Reasoning for least-term-truncation of power series

Tags: power-series

Say we have a asypomtotic power series of the general form

$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$

where the $a_n$ are constants and $x$ ist the variable. Suppose the series diverges for a given $x$. Sometimes using least term truncation, one can still finde a more or less optimal solution.

My question is now whether there is an actual proof for that or if that's really just a speculation, though a reasonable one. I've found papers discussing the subject but usually they take very specific examples that i don't find that much helpful.

Thank you!

Comment: Is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_expansion not helpful?

Comment: Look up Borel summability, exponential asymptotics, Nevanlinna-Sokal theorem, etc.

Comment: Care to engage with the comments, Hill?

Comment: I guess not. Too bad.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP refuses to engage with comments.